# Google Maps does not display my Polyline when zoomed out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As it seems to me, google made some changes to the way their google maps API displays Polylines. Up until last time I checked (3 months ago) Polylines would always be visible at all zoom-levels. When fully zoomed out, the polyline would just be a small dot on he map.

Now, using the same code (basically just the example code offered by google) when I zoom out, the polyline will disappear. This only happens, in case the waypoints of the polyline a very close together.

Example: A Polyline confined to some streets in a small town will not be visible, when zoom out completly. A Polyline which connects to points with a distance of 1000 miles will always be visible.

How can I get the short Polyline to be displayed at all zoom-levels, even if it will just be a small dot?

Example here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/v7FksNUxlpm1f6ag0iQs?p=preview

just zoom out, at some point the polyline will disappear, which I do not want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>


function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
{lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
{lat: 37.771, lng: -122.215},
{lat: 37.770, lng: -122.216},
{lat: 37.760, lng: -122.218}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 40
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for me the line doesn't disappear...which browser do you use?

Comment: chrome. the line disappears shortly after becoming a dot around zoom-level 4 or 3 I think

Comment: I see, this must be a bug. I'm afraid the best thing you can do is to report it and wait for a fix

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? having the same issue.

Comment: I reported this issue as a bug. They closed it as "works as intended". Up until now I did not find a workaround. I'm eating Fun Dip right now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Call zoomIn or zoomOut on another thread loop. (ex. setTimeout(event)

Comment: This looks more like a comment to me.